# json_decode returns error #4 in PHP

Tags: php, json

When trying to parse the below json string with `json_decode()` in PHP 5.3 I get error #4 returned which translates to `JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR`. Also [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) gives me a syntax error: `Expecting '{', '['` when manually validating.

How can I reformat this string so it can be parsed?

```
a:1:{s:18:"test";s:55:"test.pdf";}
```

Comment: @Joost I manually changed the strings, because of privacy issues, hence the incorrect lengths. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a PHP serialized string, not a JSON.
You may use `unserialize` to parse it.

Another thing, the function `json_code()` doesn't exist, you may be talking about the function `json_decode()` which transform a json string into a php array

Comment: I intended to write json_decode, I've edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can reformat this string as:

```
{"a":[1,{"s":[18,"test"],"s1":[55,"test.pdf"]}]}
```

:-)